# android - instantly swap page on swipe gesture in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a TabLayout with a ViewPager connected. I want to forbid user to drag it slowly, I mean I want ViewPager change its pages on swipe gesture with the same instant behaviour as clicking on Tabs do.
I tried to remove swipe in ViewPager, but since it's content can be really big I can't leave it as it is.

Comment: post yout code?

Comment: Well, what code do you want? I have nothing to show, just a TabLayout + ViewPager, that's it :)

Comment: Do you want to block the swipe viewpager ?

Comment: I think @Den wants swipe gesture(animation) to be as fast as when we tap the tabs of tablayout.

Comment: Exactly, without possibility to drag pages at half.